# Angular2-App user-input changes in input-field changes input-fields in other browser-instances on other machines

Tags: angular

Editing in the input-field in the browser for Angular2-App running on localhost, changes values of input-field in all other browsers running on other machines (tablet/smart-phone)

Should each device have an own instance of the Angular-Application, in its browser, don't interfering with each other?

workflow

1. I start the Angular2App with 'npm start' on lets say localhost(ip: 192.168.111.1:3000)
2. I connect from the same machine with a browser with http://localhost:3000
3. I connect from another device (e.g. Tablet, Smartphone) to Angular2App with http:/192.168.111.1:3000
4. The input-fields are displayed correct in all browsers on all devices
5. ***however*** editing in the input-field in the browser running on localhost ***changes*** values of input-field in all other browsers running on tablet/smart-phone

Code snippets:

**login.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.component.html',
  selector: 'login-comp'
    ,providers: []
    ,directives: []
})

export class LoginComponent {
  private userName: String;
  private userPw: String;
...
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div>
    <p>User: <input pInputText id="userName" (ngModel)="userName" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input pInputText id="userPw" (ngModel)="userPw" type="password"/></p>
    <p><button (click)="login()">login</button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have "browser sync" installed.
To disable this, you must set the `Node_modules\browser-sync\lib\default-config.js` to false.

```
ghostMode: {
    clicks: false,
    scroll: false,
    location: false,
    forms: {
        submit: false,
        inputs: false,
        toggles: false
    }
}
```